# Change Title/Name of Visual Studio Debugger Console

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions, console

[image]

I get confused about which project is which because each console looks the same and has the same name and title, so I want to be able to change the Title/Name of the Visual Studio Debugger Console.

I've tried changing using:

```cs
Console.Title = "My Custom Name";
```

And any other thing I've tried does not work.

Usually, the Azure Function startups look like this:

I've tried to place `Console.Title = "My Custom Title";`  before `host.Run()` and before building the HostBuilder, and inside ConfigureAppConfiguration, none of this placement works.

```cs
    public static void Main()
    {
        // initialize here because we want to be able
        LoggerConfiguration loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                  .MinimumLevel.Information()
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Error)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Core", LogEventLevel.Error)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage.Blobs", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage.Queues", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                  .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                  .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(
                       TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(),
                       TelemetryConverter.Traces,
                       LogEventLevel.Information)
                   .Enrich.FromLogContext();

        if (EnvironmentExtensions.IsDevelopment())
        {
            const string consoleOutputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception} {Properties} {NewLine}";
            loggerConfiguration.WriteTo.File(new JsonFormatter(",", formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Path.ChangeExtension($"./logs-{DateTime.Today:yyyy-MM-dd}-", ".json"), rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                                           .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: consoleOutputTemplate, formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate, applyThemeToRedirectedOutput: true);
        }
        else
        {
            loggerConfiguration
                .Enrich.WithThreadId()
                .Enrich.WithThreadName();
        }

        Log.Logger = loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger();

        IHost host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(
                worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson(),
                options =>
                {
                    // exceptions thrown by your user code may end up wrapped in an RpcException.
                    // To remove this extra layer, set the EnableUserCodeExceptions property to "true"
                    options.EnableUserCodeException = true;
                }
            )
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                        .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), optional: true);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => ConfigureAppServices(services, context.Configuration))
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, dispose: true);
            })
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

Comment: Are you writing this `Console.Title = "My Custom Name";` line in Azure function?

Comment: please share your function code as well

Comment: Not in Azure function, in Program.cs setup code, I've updated the question.

Comment: So it is an isolated function?

Comment: yes, it is an Isolated Function written in .Net 8

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/960#issuecomment-1179549563, it looks like Console.Title works for in-process function only but in case of isolated function, it won't work because the worker runs without a visible window, and in a separate process, different the the one running the host/Core Tools.

Comment: That project looks like is no longer maintained, every time I raise a question it gets ignored.

Comment: I believe you need to create a new issue

Comment: I have many open without any resolution.

Comment: @DavidPetric, Ask the same question in [MS Q&A forum of azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/87/azure-functions) category. Definitely, you'll get the resolution or PG team will inform you that they will take-up this issue if many member upvoted and commented as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, created the .NET 6 Function App and set the console title. It’s working successfully:

[image]

Then created the .NET Isolated Function App and changed the console title. It didn’t work as expected:

[image]

Observed that the isolated function app has a separate worker process and there is no impact of setting the title in the console runner.

Similar issue was reported in 2022 related to Azure-functions-dotnet-worker console name/title changing where many developers commented as it is the required functionality but it’s closed due to inactivity. Raise a new ticket in the GitHub Azure-Functions-dotnet-worker repository by referencing the previous one - [GitHub-AF-dotnet-worker-issue-960](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/960).